# Collecting data in related tables using Qfield?

Tags: qgis, qfield

recently I have started to use ArcGIS collector to collect data in the field. In collector I am able to collect a point feature or other feature class and then add entries to the related table that I have set up using a 1 to many relationship class. This allows me to collect tree entries while timber cruising or collecting data for CFI plots fairly easily.

That being said I have started to explore using QField for this work because I do not want to be stuck in the ArcGIS Online ecosystem and I like the functionality of the QGIS's Attribute form. The problem that I am running into, is not being able to collect the data on the related table that I have set up. In QGIS I am able to create a point, enter the data for that point and then add entries in the related table using the form that I have set up. Is this functionality present within QField? If it is, how can I set it up so that I can collect this related data?

Comment: If your using geopackage/spatialite you should able to do 1 to many http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/dataformat.html

Comment: I am currently using a spatialite db, but within Qfield I can't seem to add entries to the related tables

Answer (score 1):

I think this applies: http://lists.qfield.org/pipermail/users-qfield.org/2018-March/000054.html

"What's implemented so far is the possibility to view (and change) the
parent object from children.
What's not implemented so far is the possibility to view a list of
children."

A late reply, but I hope it will be useful for those who are looking for this feature. I spent a lot time myself trying to get it work, misunterpreting the meaning of the supported "Relation reference" widget.

Ciao.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152458)

Comment: I did: "What's implemented so far is the possibility to view (and change) the parent object from children. What's not implemented so far is the possibility to view a list of children." That's the essential part.